# Area of circles inside an equilateral triangle compared to the area of the triangle itself.

Tags: convergence-divergence, geometric-series

In an equilateral triangle, there is a circle (as large as possible) inside it, and in the three empty areas near each corner there are three new circles (one in each corner, each as large as possible), and between these circles and the corners there are even smaller circles (as large as possible), and the amount of circles keeps on going towards infinity. [image: like this]
How large of a portion do these circles cover of the triangle's area (percentage)? 
This problem is in a section about geometric series, and it most likely should be solved with the fact that the series of the areas of the circles converges.

Comment: Hint. Your "most likely" is most likely right. Have you tried to compute the radii (and hence the areas) of the circles of each size?

Comment: I tried but I can't figure out how. It's easy to compute the area of the biggest circle with radius R, but I don't know how to get the radius of each of the smaller ones.

Comment: Hint: as it is equilateral, you can use the property that medians intersects in 1:2 proportion. (sketch a tangent parallel to one edge)

Comment: Hint:  start with the largest circle.  Draw a line parallel to the base tangent to that circle. The small triangle on top is also equilateral so the next largest circles are incircles of equilateral triangles, and so on.

Comment: The medians itersect in a 1:2 proportion, and in an equilateral triangle aren't the medians the same lines as the angle bisectors? If so, then the radius of biggest circle would be one, and the distance from the biggest circle to a corner would be one?

Comment: Yes, you're going the right way.

Comment: Oh, let's be crude.  The triangle is of length 1.  The height is $\sqrt{3}/2$.  The three points of the circle touching the sides are (0,0), ($\pm$ 1/4, $\sqrt 3$/ 4).  The center of the circle is (0, r/2).  So $r^2/4 = 1/16 + 3/16$ so r = 1/2. Therefore the sides the height of the second smaller triangle is $\sqrt 3$/2 - 1. and the dimensions of the second triangle/circle is $(\sqrt 3/2 - 1)/(\sqrt 3/2) = 1 - 2/\sqrt 3$ as small as the first circle.  $A_n = (1-2/\sqrt 3)^n A_0$.

Comment: Do the second largest circles have a radius 1/3 of the biggest? (And the third largest 1/3 of the second largest)

Comment: Yes, 1/3.  I didn't do the circle formula right.  (I forgot to subtract the center y term, which was the radius).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the kicker: an equilateral triangle can be split into an equilateral hexagon and three congruent equilateral triangles. The incircle of the large equilateral triangle will be inscribed in the hexagon, and the area of one of the small triangles is $\frac16$ of that of the hexagon.

From this, we can show that each of the three "second-generation" circles has an are that is $\frac19$ of the "first generation" circle's area. Likewise, each "third generation" circle has an area $\frac19$ that of a "second generation" circle, and so on.

Comment: Well, that *is* easier than what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.

Let's do this.

Put the triangle at on a coordinate plane at points $A = (-1/2, 0), B = (1/2, 0), C= (0, \sqrt 3/2)$.   The inner circle touches the triangle at points $(-1/4, \sqrt 3 /4), (0,0)$ and $(1/4, \sqrt 3/4)$.  The center of the circle is $(0, r)$.

So $(1/4 - 0)^2 + (\sqrt 3/4 - r)^2 = r^2$ so $r = 1/2$.

$1/16 + 3/16 + r^2 - r\sqrt 3/2 = r^2$

$r\sqrt 3/2 =  1/4$

$r = \frac 1 {2\sqrt 3}$.

The height of the triangle is $\sqrt 3/2$.  The diameter of the big circle is $1/\sqrt 3$.  So if we imagine the smaller circle enclosed in a smaller triangle, that triangle would have height $\sqrt 3/2 - 1/\sqrt 3$.  So each iterative proportion gets smaller by $m = \frac {\sqrt 3/2 - 1/\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3/2} = 1 - 2/3 = 1/3$.

Let's multiply everything by 2 for simplicity.  The Side of the triangle is 2, and the radius of the big circle is $1/\sqrt 3$.  The proportion coefficient remains as $1/3$ though.

So the area of the triangle is $1/2 * 2 * \sqrt 3 = \sqrt 3$.  The areas of the circles are $\pi(1/\sqrt 3(1/3)^n)^2 = \pi/3^{2n + 1}$ or the total of all circles is: $\pi/3 + 3\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\pi/3^{2k + 1}$.

Comment: If the base of the triangle is from -1/2 to 1/2, its length would be 1, so how can the diameter of the biggest circle also be 1? You can't have a circle with radius 1 inside a triangle like that which has base of length 1.

Comment: Hmm, let's do this again $r^2 = (1/4)^2 + (\sqrt 3/4)^2$  is ... of eff.  I see.  hold on a sec...

Comment: My math may have errors.  I tend to make very bad calculation errors.  But I'm pretty sure my reasoning is correct.

Comment: Well, my math must be right now because of the other answers hexagon reasoning.  The ratio factor must be 1/3 as the hexagons and trianges are reducing by thirds.